# Hide referer with privoxy

Tags: linux, privoxy

How can i set a privoxy rule in the user.action file to block the referer information on any site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to stop the REFERER header from your requests to all sites you access through privoxy?

You could try something like this:

```
{ +crunch-client-header{Referer:} }
/
```

But be advised that some sites may break if you have no Referer set.